# python + how to pass variable in to os.system command

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, rhel

here is simple example how to re-scan disk `sda` from python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import os



command = "echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan"
os.system(command)
```

in case we want to set the disk as variable as `disk_name`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import os

disk_name = sda
command = "echo 1 > /sys/block/disk_name/device/rescan"
os.system(command)
```

then what is the rights approach to pass the `disk_name` variable in to command ? , or maybe other better approach ?

we tried as the following but without success

```
command = " 'echo 1 > /sys/block/' + str(disk_name) + '/device/rescan' "
os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your syntax (just remove the double-quotes, there is your mistake):

```py
command = 'echo 1 > /sys/block/' + str(disk_name) + '/device/rescan'
os.system(command)
```

But you can use an F-string to make it cleaner:

```py
command = F"echo 1 > /sys/block/{disk_name}/device/rescan"
os.system(command)
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "F"

Comment: @Judy https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/